# Emulating a rifled scaled extrusion: create rim faces between levels

Tags: transforms, extrude

**A note on what I would like to end up with:** 
The effect I want to finish with is a kind of rifled, scaled extrusion. But I would like to maximise end-effect editability. The screw modifier represents the basis of what I need, however, at every 'level' I would like to maintain control over the lattice's *simple deform bending*, rotation, and  scale.

**What I've got: My thinking at the moment:**
So, taking a look at the images I've attached; I've taken the individual plane and duplicated it to several z-altitudes, scaling and rotating each time. Each duplicate has a *simple deform* modifier associated with it.

What I would like to do now is emulate the effect of the *screw* modifier, joining each level to create rim faces.

All suggestions and questions welcome!

[image]

Comment: So you want a screw-like "tower" with this profile getting smaller towards the top? Are the colors in any way relevant or just to see it better? But I guess you don't want something like this: [profile screw](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fGeLdoT8T1G8Ms2av0MzStjVfY1EsWzH/view?usp=sharing) because it looks like your profiles are curved somehow...